# COBOL storage question about WORKING-STORAGE being allocated from HEAP

Tags: cobol, mainframe

While reading about the [enhancements made with COBOL V6.1](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048034&aid=1), i came across this information -"WORKING-STORAGE will be acquired from HEAP storage in all cases, so that there are (almost) no exceptions to when the STORAGE(xx) runtime option will affect WORKING-STORAGE.".

How will the STORAGE(XX) runtime will affect WORKING-STORAGE?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a reference document about [STORAGE(XX)](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27047580&aid=1) from IBM for COBOL 6.1.

Refer to the Storage section in the document.  How it would affect you from a performance perspective is documented in the link above and provided here for reference.

> Performance considerations using STORAGE:
>
> On the average,
>   STORAGE(00,00,00) was 11% slower than STORAGE(NONE,NONE,NONE), with a
>   range of equivalent to 133% slower. One RENT program calling a RENT
>   subprogram using IS INITIAL on the PROGRAM-ID statement with a 40 MB
>   WORKING-STORAGE was 28% slower. Note that when using call intensive
>   applications, the degradation can be 200% slower or more.
>
> On the average, STORAGE(00,NONE,NONE) was equivalent to
>   STORAGE(NONE,NONE,NONE). One RENT program calling a RENT subprogram
>   using IS INITIAL on the PROGRAM-ID statement with a 40 MB
>   WORKING-STORAGE was 5 % slower.
>
> On the average, STORAGE(NONE,00,NONE) was equivalent to STORAGE(NONE,NONE,NONE). One
>   RENT program calling a RENT subprogram using IS INITIAL on the
>   PROGRAM-ID statement with a 40 MB WORKING-STORAGE was 9% slower.
>
> For a call intensive program, STORAGE(NONE,NONE,00) can degrade more than
>   100%, depending on the number of calls.

Comment: also worth noting: The `STORAGE` runtime option is responsible for controlling the initial content of storage when it is allocated or freed and also the amount of storage. So it can affect the working storage section in terms of initial values

Answer (score 3):

`STORAGE` is a Language Environment runtime option that

> controls the initial content of storage when allocated and freed

(from "Language Environment
Customization" SA38-0685-01)

The point is that you can define different values for stack and heap storage (or you might ask to initialize one and not the other), so a program might behave differently when using uninitialized(!) WS-variables depending on whether the WS is acquired from the stack or the heap.

So the point of the sentence you quoted is that even in case of different `STORAGE`-suboptions for stack and heap the behaviout of COBOL-programs will be more consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with COBOL v6.1 working-storage is always allocated from heap unless it's in a NORENT program, where working-storage is part of the executable. (The v5.x allocation scheme is more complex and I won't go into it here.) It's local-storage that's allocated on the stack.

Also, the STORAGE() runtime option is not responsible for the amount of storage. LE doesn't in fact have an option that controls the amount of storage you get, only the increments in which storage is acquired before being parceled out to satisfy program requests.

I don't believe that the performance penalty for IS INITIAL programs seemingly attributed to STORAGE(XX) settings in the document noted earlier is actually due to the STORAGE() setting. IS INITIAL simply reapplies VALUE clauses to those items that have them, it doesn't free and reallocate working-storage.